# Python 3 setuptools on mac

Tags: macos, python-3.x, setuptools

I've installed Python 3.2 on my Mac, and I want to install some packages using setuptool's `easy_install`.

Alas, the only version of easy_install I have are (using command-line autocomplete):

```
easy_install      easy_install-2.5  easy_install-2.6
```

How can I install packages for Python 3.2?

**Addendum**

I've followed [Thomas K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434217/thomas-k)'s advice:

```
$ curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
$ python distribute_setup.py
```

But no luck, `easy_install` still installs `Python 2.6` packages:

```
$ easy_install beautifulsoup
Searching for beautifulsoup
Best match: BeautifulSoup 3.2.0
Processing BeautifulSoup-3.2.0-py2.6.egg
```

How do I force easy_install to retrieve `Python 3.2` packages instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install setuptools - or rather, the fork called 'distribute', since the original setuptools doesn't support Python 3.

There are instructions here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#installation-instructions

Comment: I've followed the instructions (see addendum), but distribute was installed on my Python 2.6.

Comment: @AdamMatan: Then you ran the install with Python 2.6. It installs in the python you use to run the install. Pretty easy and obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Like so:

```
$ curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
$ python3.2  distribute_setup.py
        ^^^
```

Or even:

```
$ curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
$ /the/path/to/the/python/where/you/want/it/installed/bin/python distribute_setup.py
```

Answer (score 0):

After following the other instructions:

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
python3.2  distribute_setup.py
```

If you've used the official Python3 package, When you install distribute_setup.py, it places the Python3 easy install script in the /Library/Frameworks part of the filesystem. To run the Python3 version of easy_install, you need to use the following as root

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/easy_install
```

Or place a symbolic link to it in /usr/local/bin:

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/easy_install-3.3 /usr/local/bin/
```